# On the equivalence between two definitions of universal hashing

Tags: discrete-mathematics, hash, cryptography

Let $H=\{h|h:X\to Y\}$, $|X|=n$, $|Y|=m$. $H$ is a universal hash family if

**Def 1.** For any $x_1,\ x_2\in X$, $x_1\neq x_2$, $\left|\left\{h\in H\middle| h(x_1)=h(x_2)\right\}\right|\leq |H|/m$. (or what if $=|H|/m$ ?)

**Def 2.** For any $x_1,\ x_2\in X$, $x_1\neq x_2$ and for any $y_1, y_2\in Y$,
$$
\Pr\limits_{h\in_u H}\left[y_1=h(x_1)\ \text{and}\ y_2=h(x_2)\right]=1/m^2.
$$

Are these two definitions equivalent? Please give some explanations.

Answer (score 0):

No.  They are not equivalent.  Consider $X=Y=\{0,1\}$ and $H$ contains two hash functions, $h_b(x)=x \oplus b$ where $\oplus$ represents the xor function.  This satisfies definition 1, but not definition 2.

See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_hashing, which explains that definition 2 is a stronger condition.

Comment: Thank you for answering. Furthermore, can these two definitions be ``asymptotically'' identical on large domains?

Comment: @KaguraHitoha, no.  Consider the case where every $h$ is a permutation (i.e., bijective function).

Comment: oh yes, you are right and that's a good counterexample. Thanks!